# Sankey chart with fixed node height

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I'm currently working on a Sankey plot using NetworkD3 library in R.
I have to plot a Sankey with fixed height irrespective of the population.

I tried using the value parameter but was able to do that for first column of nodes but for the other node columns its not working.

Here's the snippet.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(networkD3)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- read.csv( header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, 
        text = 'name,year1,year2,year3,year4
            Bob,Hilton,Sheraton,Westin,Hyatt
            Bob,Sheraton,Hilton,Westin,Hyatt
            John,Four Seasons,Ritz-Carlton,Westin,Sheraton
            Tom,Ritz-Carlton,Westin,Sheraton,Hyatt
            Mary,Westin,Sheraton,Four Seasons,Ritz-Carlton
            Sue,Hyatt,Ritz-Carlton,Hilton,Sheraton
            Barb,Hilton,Sheraton,Ritz-Carlton,Four Seasons')

View(df)

links <-
  df %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    gather('column', 'source', -row) %>%
    mutate(group = source) %>%
    mutate(column = match(column, names(df))) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    arrange(column) %>%
    mutate(target = lead(source)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    filter(!is.na(target))

View(links)

links <-
  links %>%
    mutate(source = paste0(source, '_', column)) %>%
    mutate(target = paste0(target, '_', column + 1)) %>%
    select(source, target, group)

View(links)

nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(links$source, links$target)))

View(nodes)

links$source <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
links$target <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
links$value <- 1

drop(grp)

grp <- data.frame(source=links$source)

View(grp)

grp_2<-
  grp %>% count(source)

View(grp_2)

colnames(grp_2)[which(names(grp_2) == "n")] <- "n_source"
colnames(grp_2)[which(names(grp_2) == "source")] <- "source"

View(grp_2)

links <- merge(x = links, y = grp_2, by = "source", all = TRUE)

links$value <- links$value/links$n_source

View(links)

nodes$name <- sub('_[0-9]+$', '', nodes$name)
nodes$group <- nodes$name

View(nodes)
View(links)

sankeyNetwork(sinksRight = FALSE,Links = links, Nodes = nodes, 
              Source = 'source', Target = 'target', Value = 'value', 
              NodeID = 'name',nodePadding = 1,
              LinkGroup = "group", NodeGroup = "group",fontSize = 8.7)
```

Any sort of guidance or help would go a long way! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a similar question, but your post contains way too much code with too little explanation.Try and make your post more digestible, maybe it will get a proper response then.